# Javascript Button not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm working on to-do list, I can't get the button to execute the function . What I'm I doing wrong?

```js
function displayEntry() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("entrybox").value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("display").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <input class="entrybox" type="text" value="placeholder">
  <p class="display"></p>
  <button onclick="displayEntry()">Click Me</button>
  <input type="button" name="clear" value="clear list">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing one of the elements returned by the **array** from `getElementsByClassName()`? Because it returns multiple items and the `Array` itself won't have `.value` attribute. Also, for the future reference, "wrong" doesn't help much. Tell us what is it doing *now* and what the behavior *should* be. That way the answer can be correct instead of a guessing. :)

Comment: @PeterBadida , I obviously didn't read the documentation well to know that ```getElementsByClassName ``` returns and array, which is what @Mark Schultheiss did in the answer below and it worked, Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is actually running but the selectors are not what you think they are. Couple ways to solve this but the main thing is to get the first element (0 based array of elements) you have by the class using the `[0]` after the selector.

```js
function displayEntry() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("entrybox")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
 <input class="entrybox" type="text" value="placeholder">
  <p class="display"></p>
  <button onclick="displayEntry()" type="button">Click Me</button>
  <input type="button" name="clear" value="clear list">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the javascript tag, also with an array you need to get the first element. Otherwise you can you id and getElementById.

```
 <script>
function displayEntry (){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("entrybox")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```